# How to specify required bundle version in RCP product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created new xerces bundle from jar. I can see two org.apache.xerces  bundles now - one from orbit 2.9.0 and "my" 2.11.0. If I try to export product then only the version from orbit is exported

I tried to specify version in dependency for org.apache.xerces using properties, but it does not help, the entry is also marked as erroneous (how to see the reason?).

I am using
Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

Comment: Include your plugin in your list of plugins in the .product file (or in a feature if you are using features).

Comment: that is exactly what I tried. From product file:
....
<plugins>
    ....
      <plugin id="org.apache.xerces" version="2.11.0"/>
    ....
</plugins>

Comment: If it's showing an error when you specify the version in your dependency then that suggests it can't find your `2.11.0` bundle, hence why it's falling back to the `2.9.0` version. Does the problems view not give you a reason for the error?

Comment: No I do not see problem description in Problem View. But I found the reason for the problem - I need to put qualifier also e.g. 2.11.0.201411051547. I am not sure that it is good solution.
However the primary problem is still open - export wizard does not add my version of plugin during export if I do not specify any versions and the exported application fails due to unresolved dependency to "2.11.0"
BTW the export problem appears on Ubuntu 14.04 but not on Mac for the same project. On Mac I do not specify version for export and exported product works perfectly - no dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

I missed qualifier! I need to put e.g. 2.11.0.201411051547 instead of simply 2.11.0. That is not really what I want- modifying product configuration after each plugin build, but it helps to force export of missed bundle.