# is there an Eclipse Product Export Wizard setting to set Locations to resolve plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My Eclipse product launch configurations (based on plugins), the Target Definitions, and the Manifest all have the latest versions of dependency plugins, they get resolved without any errors, and the launch works.

This is an Eclipse Mars.2 release 4.5.2 and software updates are being performed by Oomph which puts the plugins in its bundle pool. This bundle pool is being looked up by all the above, since all the latest versions of plugins are displayed as selected.

However PDE maintains another bundle pool as part of metadata in the workspace,   this contains older versions and it appears the Product Export Wizard exports from there if it finds any version of a dependency plugin.

There are a couple of Stack Overflow questions which suggest a solution of manually specifying to the product Export Wizard the full version for each plugin:

[How to specify required bundle version in RCP product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762426/how-to-specify-required-bundle-version-in-rcp-product)

[Eclipse RCP - Wrong plugin version gets exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666311/eclipse-rcp-wrong-plugin-version-gets-exported)

but this gets painful when one has lots of dependencies and multiple products.

Is there a way to direct the Product Export Wizard on lookup locations?

Comment: I think the export wizard use the current Target Platform for the lookup - have you configured a Target Platform?

Comment: Yes, in my Target Platform preferences I have an Active Target Definition which is using as Locations ${eclipse_home} plus a couple of update sites. It resolves the Target Contents with no errors.The Content shows all versions of the plugins i.e. the latest ones that are in Oomph's bundle pool and the older ones that are in the PDE's metadata bundle pool. It seems to know where to find all versions but the export apparently takes the jars only from the PDE metadata bundle pool - unless, as the two proposed answers in the links suggest you manually specify full versions for each plugin.

Comment: I would use a Target Platform that does not use eclipse_home. Build the definition from scratch specifying the exact repositories you want to use.

Comment: Many thanks, Greg, for your very prompt replies and helpful suggestions.

Comment: Many thanks, Greg, for your very prompt replies and helpful suggestions. In fact I had created a new definition before I saw your second comment and I used ${eclipse-home} and the exported product runs. I tried it without  ${eclipse_home} and it fails to resolve some plugins - I could solve this by looking for each but ... I don't fully understand what the problem was/is with definitions but it does seem possible to export without manually specifying the versions. Thanks once again.

Comment: Minor increase in my understanding of what is going on with these Target Definitions: My new Target Definition resulted in the PDE metadata bundle pool being updated with the latest versions of plugins. (I had to define Locations and included 4.5.2 update site) That is why this export works, the previous failed. So still consistent with Product Export Wizard resolving from the "wrong" bundle pool.

Comment: You were right - as usual - Greg! I finally stopped being lazy and redid the Target Definition without using ${eclipse_home} as you suggested and entered the Oomph bundle pool and updates sites and the PDE export wizard picks from there. If you enter your comment as an answer, if I have the rights I will acknowledge it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually best to use a Target Platform that does not use eclipse_home. Build the definition from scratch specifying the exact repositories you want to use.

Comment: Right answer, solved my problem but my reputation remains too low to vote ! Sorry !